# How to solve Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED this error

Tags: android, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> Multiple build operations failed.
> Cannot parse result path string:
> Cannot parse result path string:
> Cannot parse result path string:
> Cannot parse result path string:
> Cannot parse result path string:
> Cannot parse result path string:

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4m 11s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'. > Multiple build operations failed. Cannot parse result path string:  Cannot parse result path string:  Cannot parse result path string:  > Cannot parse result path string:  > Cannot parse result path string:  > Cannot parse result path string:  * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 4m 11s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Build Succesfull.....

Answer (score 0):

At Path android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true //Add this line
}
```

Comment: Same error repeated ...

Comment: keep multiDexEnabled true and 
add implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' in your anroid/app/build.gradle and if your already have this implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' replace it with implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'.